# Vapor Deployment Pipeline Test "Ensure Environment Is Healthy" Failing on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-vapor

I'm facing an issue with a deployment pipeline test in Laravel's Vapor named "**Ensure Environment Is Healthy**" that keeps failing. I'm relatively new to AWS, and the project was initially set up by someone else. I'm trying to navigate and understand where the issue could be coming from.

The last time of the project being deployed, six months ago, this pipeline test did not exist. It seems to have been added by AWS in the meantime, but I can't really find anything about it.

- [Screenshot of deployment pipeline on Vapor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T1zA.jpg)
- [Screenshot of the only log entry about it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glsJl.png)

As you can see, failed "Ensure Environment Is Healthy" test. Locally, however, I have no problems at all. This is my vapor.yml file:

```
id: 29629
name: theprojectname
environments:
    production:
        memory: 1024
        cli-memory: 512
        runtime: 'php-8.0:al2'
        storage: theprojectname-storage-production
        database: theprojectname-production
        build:
            - 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install --no-dev'
            - 'php artisan event:cache'
        deploy:
            - 'php artisan migrate --force'
    staging:
        memory: 1024
        cli-memory: 512
        runtime: 'php-8.0:al2'
        storage: theprojectname-storage-staging
        database: theprojectname-production
        build:
            - 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install --no-dev'
            - 'php artisan event:cache'
        deploy:
            - 'php artisan migrate --force'
            # - 'php artisan db:seed --force'
```

I'm happy if someone has the slightest idea how to fix this. I want to understand the test for this, be able to fix it or even at least disable it. Thank you everyone!

- I tried in vapor.yml to increase the timeout time to a maximum, but it did nothing.
- I searched AWS for possible error messages and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is like timeout, but for `Ensure Environment Is Healthy` i always look at CLI log errors, if you can find anything then by fixing it this issue will be solved.

About the changing timeout that did nothing, you need to keep in mind that Vapor has three lambda function, so if you had any errors you need to know which function you are in to check the logs. Because vapor has three lambda function for each one of them you can set different timeouts.

1. Http
2. CLI
3. Queue

So if you increase the Http timeout it wont effect the cli function.

Comment: I am trying to figure out. I have the exact same error. I tried anything. Any help?